# wordpress site won't stay centered on desktop browser during width resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Site in progress: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

I've been banging my head against the wall over this for hours - when I resize my browsers width (by dragging the browser window's right resize handle) my site maintains that nice responsive centered effect I want for roughly 1/8th of my browsers window size. However when I drag the browser's right window resize handle from right to left past this point (roughly 1/8th the width of the browser window, when the browser window is taking up the full width of my 1080p screen) my site (header, content, and footer) stops staying centered and the resize handle crops over the site rather than maintaining the responsive centering that I'm looking to achieve.

I've tried applying the "margin: o auto;" trick to the body class and the wrapper class individually and simultaneously, but it doesn't yield the desired results.

I'm really at a loss for ideas here. Can anyone offer some insight please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the width from body class and margin also need to set margin:0px;

Comment: Unfortunately this fix stretches every element who's size is defined by a percentage proportionately to the browser width. This isn't what I'm going for. Thanks for your reply though. Should I be using pixels to define the elements I don't want to stretch with the screen & use your fix? I was under the impression one should use percentages to define things like width, line-height, margins etc in order to maintain a responsive site across multiple screen resolutions... is this not true? I could really use some help on this matter please! Thanks all!

Comment: In such case you need to give the min-width of <section role="main">. By doing this it'll not disturbing the layout in lower resolutions. If you really need to give the body width with pixels. In such case you calculate the screenwidth and set your css accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Arfan, I've managed to solve the problem using some of the advice you've provided. After much thinking and a day or two away from the site, it seems the best solution to achieve my desired results are to use a set width of 960px for the body class and change the size of the elements that were originally defined by percentages (and were getting warped due to the change of the body width) to be defined by pixels instead. Then I will use media queries to specify the size of these elements given different screen resolutions. Thanks SO for your help!